# How to add border photo on the thumbnail preview Dropzone Js?

Tags: dropzone.js

Hi i have dropzone Js Upload just working, but i need to add i border to the picture that i clicked on the Thumb Preview of dropzone js.

How i Can do that ?

I have this code :

```
 defaultButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          // Remove the file preview.
          //_this.removeFile(file);
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{!! route('setDefaultPhoto' ) !!}" ,
                data: { id : file.serverid },
                dataType: 'JSON'
            });

        });
```

Comment: use css for it img:focus

Comment: That nice Aproach but i just figure out. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
.dz-image { border: 1px solid #000 }
```